# Вывод xsl в таблицу

Tags: xml, xslt

Вопрос по xsl
Задача в следующем: вывести график отпусков для сотрудников в виде таблице:
в строке сотрудник - 48 столбцов для кварталов месяца.
Запрос формирует xml, в котором для каждого сотрудника строится список кварталов месяца, на которые запланированы отпуска. Нужно вывести этот xml.
Задача не совсем по моему профилю, поэтому инструментом владею поверхностно.
Проблема в следующем:
Шапка таблицы строю следующем образом:

```
    <TR>
        <TD class = "Title">ФИО</TD>
        <xsl:for-each select = "VOCATIONS_LIST/WEEEK_LIST/WEEK">
            <TD><xsl:value-of select="@ID"/></TD>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </TR>
```

Далее хочется циклом по сотрудникам выводить информацию об отпусках, но так как для каждого сотрудника кол-во кварталов будет ограничено, то как заполнить всю строку с 48 неделями? Не хочется для каждого сотрудника строить список из 48 элементов и помечать те,  на которые у него совпал отпуск

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вот так, если кому интересно. Правда некоторая избыточность всё-таки осталась.
Не претендую на оптимальность и правильность кода

```
<TABLE style = "border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:black;">
    <TR>
        <TD class = "Title">ФИО</TD>
        <xsl:for-each select = "VOCATIONS_LIST/WEEEK_LIST/WEEK">
            <TD class="Weeks"><xsl:value-of select="@ID"/></TD>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </TR>
    <xsl:for-each select = "VOCATIONS_LIST/STAFF_LIST/STAFF">
        <TR>
            <TD><xsl:value-of select="PEOPLE_NAME"/></TD>
            <xsl:variable name="StaffID" select="@ID" />  
            <xsl:for-each select = "../../WEEEK_LIST/WEEK">
                <xsl:variable name="WeekID" select="@ID" />     
                <TD>
                    <xsl:if test="../../STAFF_LIST/STAFF/PLAN_VOCATION_LIST/WEEK[@ID=$WeekID][@STAFF_ID=$StaffID]">
                        <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">black</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="../../STAFF_LIST/STAFF/VOCATION_LIST/WEEK[@ID=$WeekID][@STAFF_ID=$StaffID]">
                        <font style="font-family:Wingdings 3;color:red">&#136;</font>
                    </xsl:if>&#160;
                </TD>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </TR>
    </xsl:for-each>
</TABLE>
```